# Python - Printed Output Goes On Different Lines

Tags: python, html, optimization

When I'm trying to output my code, it goes on some random lines and the last line is fine. I'm a beginner. Just started 20 minutes ago.

```
f = open('gamelist.txt')

text = f.readlines()
for line in text:
    print('<div><a href="genericweb'+line+'.html">'+line+'</a></div>')
```

***THIS IS MY OUTPUT***

```
<div>
  <a
    href="genericwebabc
  .html"
    >abc
  </a>
</div>
<div>
  <a
    href="genericwebdef
  .html"
    >def
  </a>
</div>
<div><a href="genericwebghi.html">ghi</a></div>
```

As you can see, the first two don't work, but the last one does. The text document is: "abc  def  ghi". ***New lines in between each group of letters btw.***  Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may use :

```
print('<div><a href="genericweb'+line+'.html">'+line+'</a></div>', end=' ')
```

or try using this to get rid of newline :

```
for line in text:
    line = line.rstrip('\n')
    print('<div><a href="genericweb'+line+'.html">'+line+'</a></div>')
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can set the [end](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) keyword-parameter to an empty string, and it will not print any ending (the newline). This parameter defaults to "\n", the escape for a newline. Setting it to be blank will cause this newline not to be printed. You can also set it to any other string to write a different end.

```py
print("hello", end="")
```

You should probably take a look at [Jinja2](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/) for HTML templating in python.